# PHP - Accessing data within array

Tags: php, arrays

Can't seem to work out how to access data within an array that has other arrays within it.

My array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 28
            [serv_image] => 
            [serv_name] => My Service
            [slug] => my-service
            [is_featured] => 
            [_blocks] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [anchor_heading] => Mats Heading
                            [_block_type] => anchorHeading
                            [_block_id] => pe8t69
                            [_block_index] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [anchor_heading] => Another anchored heading
                            [_block_type] => anchorHeading
                            [_block_id] => pea49u
                            [_block_index] => 1
                        )

                )

            [_page] => *
            [_pageID] => 1
            [_sortvalue] => 1003
        )

)
```

So far I've tried this without success:

```
foreach($services as $service) {
    print_r($service['_blocks']['anchor_heading']);
}
```

This results in undefined index on `anchor_heading`.

**UPDATE**

I will have an unknown amount of these that I need to group together into a variable. How can I ensure I'm grabbing them all, no matter how many other times it's been entered?

Comment: `$service['_blocks'][0]['anchor_heading']` - you are jumping over one layer/hierachie. (and '_block' is '_blocks')

Comment: for the sake of better understanding, accesing data inside the $service array will follow the following path: `$service[$i][_blocks][$j]['field']` ... I replaced numeric indexes with variables `$i` and  `$j` just for show. Whenever there's one of those, you'd need to use a foreach loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use 2 times a `foreach` and echo the value of anchor_heading:

```
foreach($services as $service) {
    foreach ($service["_blocks"] as $block) {
        echo $block["anchor_heading"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an array for each _block  .. so you need   an indexed access  ..  (or an inner iteration)

```
foreach($services as $service) {
  print_r($service['_blocks'][0]['anchor_heading']);
  print_r($service['_blocks'][1]['anchor_heading']);
}
```

(or an inner iteration)

```
  foreach($services as $service) {
      $blocks  = $service['_blocks'];
      foreach( $blocks as $block) {
          print_r($block['anchor_heading']);

      }
  }
```

Comment: If I have a changing amount of these / unknown amount, is there a way I can just ensure im grabbing as many as are there, sort of thing?

Comment: that would be the 'inner iteration': another `foreach($service['_blocks'] as $block)` inside

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to access the data within your array in a for loop:

```
print($service['_blocks'][0]['anchor_heading']);
```